# Constraint UITableView to InputAccessory

Tags: swift, keyboard, tableview, dismiss, inputaccessoryview

I have a chat-like UI in my app, so I have a bottom bar, which is the inputAccessoryView and my tableView. What I want to do is to properly resize the tableView when keyboard goes onscreen and offscreen. However, simply constraining the bottom of the tableView to the top of the inputAccessoryView doesn't seem to be possible. So how do I achieve this Messages-like behavior from my app?

[image: View Hirearchy]

viewDidLoad() for my controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    noteTableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(Double.pi));
    noteTableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive


    noteTableView.delegate = self
    noteTableView.dataSource = self

    [...]

}
```

And here are the two functions for getting my inputAccessoryView to actually work

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        get {
            return inputBar
        }
}

override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
}
```

I also have a tap gesture recognizer on my textField inside the inputAccessory which switches it's behavior from a 'button' to a proper textfield, so here's a bit from there.

```
@objc func newButtonTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    [...]

    inputBar.inputField.isSelectable = true
    inputBar.inputField.isEditable = true
    inputBar.inputField.becomeFirstResponder()

    [...]

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **iOS 15** Apple introduced `keyboardLayoutGuide` which is a `UILayoutGuide` dynamically following keyboard changes (even the keyboard floating mode on iPad).

So all you have to do is:

```
myTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.keyboardLayoutGuide.TopAnchor)
```

Read more about Keyboard Layout Guide on [Apple's Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/keyboards_and_input/adjusting_your_layout_with_keyboard_layout_guide) or watch the [WWDC21 Session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10259/).