# iOS adjusting bottom constraint constant of view when keyboard visible has a larger offset on newer model iPhones

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, notificationcenter

I am setting up my keyboard will show notifier, getting the keyboard height, and setting the constant value on the bottom constraint as shown here:

Notification Observer

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Keyboard Will Show Function

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
        return
    }

    _keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
    changeStateContainerBottomConstraint.constant = _keyboardHeight
}
```

However on newer models of phones the value I am getting back is placing the view higher than the top of the keyboard as shown in the screenshots below. I am hesitant to adjust the constraint with a static value as that could change in the future, or from model to model. Has anyone else come across this issue and have a solution?

iPhone SE Screenshot
[image]

iPhone 14 Pro Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I've found a workable solution. Just needed to find the bottom value of the safe area insets and subtract it from the returned height. Here is what `keyboardWillShow` looks like now

```
 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let keyboardFrame = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else {
        return
    }

    _keyboardHeight = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue.height
    let bottom: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
    changeStateContainerBottomConstraint.constant = _keyboardHeight - bottom
}
```

Comment: A simpler solution is to use `keyboardLayoutGuide`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69145739/20287183 for an example.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you look at this framework `https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager` which is the most popular library to handle this kind of stuff. It's easier to use with a few lines of code like `IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true` in your AppDelegate file.

Comment: I'd prefer a native solution. I've found in the past that relying heavily on 3rd part libraries isn't very sustainable.